# Server based syntax highlighting in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

Why are some keywords highlighted blue and some gray in SQL Server Management Studio?

And why does the UNION keyword highlight as gray when connected to a SQL Server 2000 database, but blue when connected to a SQL Server 2005 database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are reserved words. We have a table called Order in our production DB (Before I started!), which is annoying.

Edit:

Sorry, misread you. Blue = Keyword, Gray = Operator. Full list of colpurs: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=sqlserver&seqNum=177 about halfway down.